# How to add add image in center of cell image in suitable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want add image into the center of the cell image.I have cell image so if the cell is a video then i want to add a play icon in center of the cell image.I have tried following code but this does not work.please tell me how can i solve this?

```
  if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [cell.img_post_thumbnail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
            CGPoint centerImageView = cell.img_post_thumbnail.center;
            centerImageView.x = self.view.center.x;
            centerImageView.y = self.view.center.y;

            UIImageView *playIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(centerImageView.x, centerImageView.y,20,20)];
            playIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"];
            [cell.img_post_thumbnail addSubview:playIcon];




        }
```

**Edit:**
    Image is centred but not scaled as per size given.

```
[cell.img_post_thumbnail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];


float btn_width = cell.frame.size.width * (5/ 320.0);
float btn_height = cell.frame.size.height * (5 / 568.0);

UIImageView *playIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,btn_width,btn_height)];
playIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"];
playIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[cell.img_post_thumbnail addSubview:playIcon];


float btn_selfRatio=(btn_width/btn_height);
float btn_superRatio=(btn_width/playIcon.frame.size.height);

[playIcon addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:playIcon attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:btn_selfRatio constant:0]];

[cell.img_post_thumbnail addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.img_post_thumbnail attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:btn_superRatio constant:0]];


[[cell img_post_thumbnail] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:[cell img_post_thumbnail]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             multiplier:1.0
                               constant:0.0]];

[[cell img_post_thumbnail] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:[cell img_post_thumbnail]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1.0
                               constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: for set image or anything at the center of your cell you can set XPosition of ImageView like :( cell.frame.size.with - UIImage.frame.size ) / 2

Comment: Please post complete answer i could not understand

Comment: Why using self.view.center.x/y ? It should be centerImageView.x = cell.contentView.center.x respectively. Or cell.frame.size.width/2 for X and height/2 for y

Comment: I still dont understand, why you want to add image at the centre point of image view ? you can simply create imageview with respect to image and make that imageview centre to the cell!!!

Comment: you dont need to calculate centre point twice!!!!

Comment: can you post the code.I am fresher in iOS @Mr.T

Comment: or you can apply horizontal and vertical alignment constraints to your image view and it will place your imageview at the centre of the cell.

Comment: are you creating the elements programmatically? or do you have storyboard layout ?

Comment: Play icon will be dynamic according to my need.

Comment: do you mean the size varies for your image view ?

Comment: what is cell.img_post_thumbnail? Is it another imageview ?

Comment: please post a screenshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes image size vary with image view

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using auto layout:

```
[[cell img_post_thumbnail] addConstraint:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:[cell img_post_thumbnail]
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];

[[cell img_post_thumbnail] addConstraint:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:playIcon
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:[cell img_post_thumbnail]
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];
```

**EDIT**

Oh and remember setting `[[cell img_post_thumbnail] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` when creating views programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
playIcon.center = cell.img_post_thumbnail.center;


viewWantedToCenter.center = baseView.center;//The view on which you wanted to center  "viewWantedToCenter" view.
```

Comment: please give me the NSLOgs following

Comment: NSLog(@"cell.img_post_thumbnail:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.img_post_thumbnail.frame));

Comment: NSLog(@"cell.img_post_thumbnail:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(cell.img_post_thumbnail.center));

Comment: NSLog(@"playIcon:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(playIcon.frame));

Comment: NSLog(@"playIcon:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(playIcon.center));

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat width = 20.0;
CGFloat height = 20.0;
CGFloat xPos = (cell.img_post_thumbnail.frame.size.width - width)/2;
CGFloat yPos = (cell.img_post_thumbnail.frame.size.height - height)/2;

UIImageView *playIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos,width,height)];

    playIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"];
    [cell.img_post_thumbnail addSubview:playIcon];
```

i hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly match the centres of the two imageviews like this

```
    UIImageView *playIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,20,20)];
    playIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"];

    playIcon.center = cell.img_post_thumbnail.center;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:playIcon];
```